# Why Tokyo Tyrant so slow

Tags: tokyo-tyrant

I have follow situation tyrant server lunched on freebsd host, like this:

ttserver -uas -log /data/tyrant/1.log -sid 1 -thnum 8 -tout 5 /data/tyrant/data/1.tct

And i try to communicate this server on windows from python and pyrant-0.3.5: like this:

```
import pyrant;
import time;

t = pyrant.Tyrant(host="192.168.0.220", port=1978);
tbegin = time.time();

for i in xrange(4000000):
  if i and ((i % 10000) == 0):
    print time.time() - tbegin;
    tbegin = time.time();

  t[i] = {"text": "ruslan text", "value": i};
```

and have i think very slow performance about 5-6 per 10,000 records. But if i start this code on the same machine like server(ttserver). Performance are good - about 0.5 sec per 10,000 records

What i must do to workaround this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I know this may be too obvious, but did you measure the latency to the server? This could be the bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

you can tracert www.ttserver.com and look at the latency from your native host to the remote server. maybe it's the cause.